# Inheriting from a C++ class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c++, inheritance, v8

I'm using V8 in a C++ program for extensions. I want to be able to
create objects in JavaScript that "inherit" from a base class in C++.
This is a simple hierarchy in C++:

```
class animal
{
public:
    void move();
    virtual void vocalize() = 0;
};

class cat : public animal
{
public:
    void vocalize() override;
    void ignore_owner();
};
```

This is `cat` implemented in JavaScript instead of C++:

```
function cat()
{
    this.vocalize = function() {}
    this.ignore_owner = function() {}
}

add_animal(new cat);
```

where `add_animal()` is a global function implemented in C++:

```
void add_animal(v8::Local<v8::Object> o);
```

In `add_animal()`, I manually add the `move` property pointing to a C++
function and make sure that the `vocalize` property exists and is a
function.

```
var c = new cat;

c.ignore_owner();   // JavaScript code
c.move();           // error, undefined

add_animal(c);

c.move();           // okay, C++ code
```

My experience in JavaScript outside of web pages is limited. Is this a
scheme that makes sense? The fact that `add_animal()` is used to both
add the "base class" properties *and* add the animal to a list looks
counter-intuitive to me. I could add a second function:

```
var c = new cat;
make_animal(c);
add_animal(c);
```

but this requires discipline and looks convoluted.

I could also expose `animal`, use it to create objects and add the
`cat`-specific properties afterwards:

```
function make_cat(c)
{
    c.vocalize = function() {}
    c.ignore_owner = function() {}
}

var c = new animal;
make_cat(c);

add_animal(c);
```

but this looks weird to me.

What is the best way to "inherit" from a C++ class?

Comment: This is really not a straightforward problem, as C++ and Javascript inheritance mechanisms have **fundamental** differences. This by itself might be an "architecture smell" hinting that it's not a good idea to do this.

Comment: Which is why "inherit" in is quotes. I need a simple way to create a javascript object with predefined properties while being easy to extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expose your base class to JavaScript (see [the official embedder's guide](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Embedder's-Guide#accessing-dynamic-variables) for an example), and then use regular JavaScript inheritance:

```
function Cat(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
var catproto = Cat.prototype = new Animal();
catproto.vocalize = function() { /* cat-specific override */ }
catproto.ignore_owner = function() { return true; /* :-P */ }
catproto.purr = function() { /* you can add new methods too */ }

var c = new Cat("Kitty");
c.move();  // Inherited.
c.vocalize();  // Meow.
```

Comment: I had completely forgotten this question! This pet project (no pun intended) of mine is long gone, so I can't test this, but I'll accept your answer nonetheless.